# Load a SQl query in pyspark?

Tags: sql, oracle, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to read a sql script straight from the oracle sql using pyspark?
I have been loading two tables in pyspark and tried to join them, It takes a long time to do that in pyspark and I need to join even more tables(6 tables). This does not take much time in Oracle Sql.

So how can I read and run a "X.sql" file with pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found one solution:

```
with open("C:\Desktop\Project\Alerts.sql") as Al:
   Alert= Al.read()
results = sqlctx.sql(Alert)
```